# Does GABA enhance or inhibit negative effects of glutamate?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology, pharmacology, psychoneuropharmacology

A [study on NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5494581/) studied the correlation between a depressive mood and chronic pain. I researched this because today I noticed unusual emotional volatility as a result of 2 days of acute back pain combined with acute muscle soreness (DOMS).

I am certain that the pain and difficulty sleeping (although I slept in on both days), and challenges with finding a sleeping position without pain, and continuous pain on most moving, standing, and sitting, that this has caused some emotional volatility on a physiological level. (Psychological effects as a direct result of temporary chemical changes in the body/brain due to acute pain; not due to neural pathways causing depression, of which I do not have, and I am a joyful person normally).

This question is not about alleviating pain, as it will go away on its own soon. The back is getting near healed by end of week and the sore muscles which have DOMS due to intense workout will also resolve on its own in a few days to a week.

Rather, my question is specifically concerning a particular phrase which I am unclear about:

> Glutamatergic activity can be promoted through the breakdown of efficient inhibition of the actions of glutamate by GABA

I am unclear if this is stating that GABA reduces the effects of glutamate or if it enhances the effects.

There is no clear answer to my full [temporary] issue, since the study itself states that `neither the corresponding pathophysiological mechanisms of chronic pain and depression nor their mutual correlation has been identified`, so there is no pathophysiological scientific answer to the chemical workings, so I can only speculate.

The end result is I wanted to discover whether increasing or lowering GABA could have any effect on my mood as a result of my pain in the short term, which is easily experimented rather safely by either taking GABA or taking a supplement that inhibits GABA. It could have no beneficial effect - no problem. It's worth a try though. I've taken GABA before BTW.

To reiterate the particular question: With regards to the statement:

> Glutamatergic activity can be promoted through the breakdown of efficient inhibition of the actions of glutamate by GABA

Does this imply that GABA enhances or reduces glutamatergic activity?

***Note:**
I think it's saying that GABA creates glutamatergic activity which inhibits the neuroexcitatory effects of glutamate. That is, taking GABA would decrease effects of glutamate. Let me know if this is correct or not.*

Comment: It would be possible to rewrite this question without the personal medical details, but please don't use such an answer to do anything besides understand biology. In any event, it certainly is not as simple as eating GABA increases GABA in the nervous system (no matter what someone trying to sell you a bottle of GABA might say).

Answer (score -1):

Glutamate causes an EPSP (Excitatory Post Synaptic Potential,) thereby making the neuron less negative depolarize) and closer to voltage required to cause an Action Potential (AP)  and thus fire.  GABA causes an IPSP (Inhibitory Post Synaptic Potential) making the neuron more negative (hyperpolarize) and further away from the voltage required to fire and cause an AP.  GABA & Glutamate receptors  are generally on different neurons that synapse with other interneurons & oppose each other, although neither one is generally the end neurotransmitter of the locus,  nor the only neurotransmitter of the neuron, so basically act as neuromodulators on the post-synaptic neuron. Glutamatergic receptors generally affect Sodium Channels &  GABA-ergic neurons generally  affect Chloride Channels. In theory, inhibiting an inhibitory neuron would be the equivalent of exciting an excitatory neuron, but since they primarily affect  post-synaptic neurons, the effect is cumulative, so the post-synaptic interneuron is basically adding up all the EPSPs & IPSPs to get a RMP (Resting Membrane Potential) & some additional stimulus must occur to get the neuron to fire (AP)

Comment: You might recheck what you've written here because a lot of this answer is incorrect or at least mis-written.